# Non Separable ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a function in the following form.

$$P = \frac{K_1}{2} U\left[\sqrt{\frac{2K_1}{K_2 U^2} + 1} +1\right]$$

where $P =\dfrac{dE}{dt}$ and $U =\dfrac{dS}{dt}$

I want to find energy $E$ required to travel distance $S$.
If I integrate both sides with respect to $dt$ **I think** i will get what I want. but how to do it ?

Can anyone point this out to me ?

Thanks

PS : This is not a homework problem. I'm just a curious old man who is not  good at maths.

Comment: Manipulating the RHS yields \begin{align}
P&=\sqrt{\frac{K_{1}^{3}}{2K_{2}}+\frac{K_{1}^{2}U^{2}}{4}}+\frac{K_{1} U}{2} \\
\implies \left(P-\frac{K_{1}U}{2}\right)^{2} &= \frac{K_{1}^{3}}{2K_{2}}+\frac{K_{1}^{2}U^{2}}{4} \\
\implies P&=\frac{K_{1}U}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2K_{1}}}\sqrt{2K_{1}K_{2}U^{2}+4K_{1}^{3}} \\
\implies E&=\int\frac{K_{1}S'}{2}dt\pm\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2K_{1}}}\int\sqrt{2K_{1}K_{2}S'^{2}+4K_{1}^{3}}dt \end{align} The first integral can be handled explicitly, the second requires the use of the [Euler-Lagrange equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Lagrange_equation).

Comment: I get that $S = At + B$ for some constants $A$ and $B$ (it's almost identical to the example problem on the Wikipedia page I linked).